# Get SelectedValue of RadioButtonList on SelectedIndexChanged event in a datalist using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a `DataList` in which there are 2 `Label` and a `RadioButtonList`. The 2 `Label` contains question ID and the question in which the Question ID is hidden, and the `RadioButtonList` contains the options. All these controls are bounded. Here's the code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Que_id" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question_id") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever user selects an option in the `RadioButtonList` the selected option and its question id should get stored in the database. It's easy to store the whole `DataList` at the button click event, but I want to store the response side by side as the user selects the option for a particular question.
I don't know how to get the question ID on `SelectedIndexChanged` event but I tried the following code on `SelectedIndexChanged` to get the selected option value but this too doesn't work.

```
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)DataList1.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
string answer=rbl.SelectedValue;
```

For more clarification, I brought this data from database in a `DataSet` and filtered it for the question ID, question and options. The values are being set during the Page_Load in the if(!IsPostBack).

Comment: Need info on which state you are setting the values in code behind. Is this Page Load?

Can you try `if(!IsPostBack)` - set you radio button list data

or try below,

`string fooValue = "foo"; `
`// consider "foo" is saved at dabase. Assign it into a variable and use it`
`rbl.SelectedIndex=
rbl.Items.IndexOf(rbl.Items.FindByValue(fooValue));`

Comment: @Thennarasan provided the information, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

modify

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
```

To

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" OnItemCommand="DataList1_command" runat="server">
```

Assuming you have a `<asp:Button` and id as `button1` and OnClick  as `bclick`

```
void bclick(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            HtmlInputRadioButton radio = (item.FindControl("radioButton") as HtmlInputRadioButton);
            if (radio.Checked)
            {
                // this is you checked radio
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please rea the question Carefully, I can do this quiet easily but what I'm trying to do is get data during OnSelectedIndexChanged event not on the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HiddenField to store the question ID in the DataList (it is more "natural" than an invisible Label):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenQuestionID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("question_id") %>' />
```

In the event handler of the RadioButtonList, you can use the `sender` parameter to retrieve the control, and then get the selected value. The `NamingContainer` of the RadioButtonList also contains the HiddenField, from which you can get the question ID:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList rbl = sender as RadioButtonList;
    string answer = rbl.SelectedValue;
    HiddenField hiddenQuestionID = rbl.NamingContainer.FindControl("hiddenQuestionID") as HiddenField;
    string questionID = hiddenQuestionID.Value;
    ...
}
```